# How to use the same nested serializer for both create and listing

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I need to use the same serializer for both create and listing.

Here is my serializer:

```
class OfficeSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    employees = EmployeeSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    state = StateSerializer(read_only=True)
    country = CountrySerializer(read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Office
        exclude = ['office_id']
```

I am using this serializer for listing the office API, am I able to use the same serializer for creating as well?

This is my views.py

```
class OfficeCreateView(CreateAPIView):
    queryset = Office.objects.order_by('id').all()
    serializer_class = OfficeSerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save()
```

In this case all the fields are saving excluding employees, state, country etc.

```
class OfficeSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    employees = EmployeeSerializer(many=True)
    state = StateSerializer()
    country = CountrySerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = Office
        exclude = ['office_id']
```

If I remove the read_only field I am getting the following error in Postman

```
{
    "employees": [
        "This field is required."
    ],
    "state": [
        "This field is required."
    ],
    "country": [
        "This field is required."
    ]
}
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: When you removed the read_only, were you passing the data for employees, state, and country nested in office? Also, if you want to have nested serializer that can save objects, you need to add some extra code, see the doc. https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers

Answer (score 0):

In 'class Meta:' , you can take advantage of 'read_only_fields = (, ...)'